# Laravel Blade @includeIfElse?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is there an @includeIfElse directive available with Laravel Blade?

Basically I would like to include another template if it exists, otherwise include another template.

Does this functionality exist?  How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such directive but you may use something like this:

```
@if(view()->exists('view.name'))
    @include('view.name')
@else
    @include('other.view.name')
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could one line it like this, if you felt the need:

```
@include(view()->exists('view.name') ? 'view.name' : 'other.view.name')
```

Comment: thanks!  I accepted the other answer only because my view names are long enough that a one-liner would be a little harder to read.  However I will certainly keep that version in my backpocket.